# Fatal error: Call to undefined function: strripos()

Tags: php

I get this error only in safari and the android browser. All my code does is redirect the page based on the browser? works fine everywhere else, any suggestions
?

> "Fatal error: Call to undefined function: strripos() in /home/content/a/l/i/aliahealthcare/html/Register-With-Alia.php on line 65"

```
<?php
 function getBrowser() 
{ 
$u_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']; 
$bname = 'Unknown';
$platform = 'Unknown';
$version= "";

//First get the platform?
if (preg_match('/linux/i', $u_agent)) {
    $platform = 'linux';
}
elseif (preg_match('/macintosh|mac os x/i', $u_agent)) {
    $platform = 'mac';
}
elseif (preg_match('/windows|win32/i', $u_agent)) {
    $platform = 'windows';
}

// Next get the name of the useragent yes seperately and for good reason
if(preg_match('/MSIE/i',$u_agent) && !preg_match('/Opera/i',$u_agent)) 
{ 
    $bname = 'Internet Explorer'; 
    $ub = "MSIE"; 
} 
elseif(preg_match('/Firefox/i',$u_agent)) 
{ 
    $bname = 'Mozilla Firefox'; 
    $ub = "Firefox"; 
} 
elseif(preg_match('/Chrome/i',$u_agent)) 
{ 
    $bname = 'Google Chrome'; 
    $ub = "Chrome"; 
} 
elseif(preg_match('/Safari/i',$u_agent)) 
{ 
    $bname = 'Apple Safari'; 
    $ub = "Safari"; 
} 
elseif(preg_match('/Opera/i',$u_agent)) 
{ 
    $bname = 'Opera'; 
    $ub = "Opera"; 
} 
elseif(preg_match('/Netscape/i',$u_agent)) 
{ 
    $bname = 'Netscape'; 
    $ub = "Netscape"; 
} 

// finally get the correct version number
$known = array('Version', $ub, 'other');
$pattern = '#(?<browser>' . join('|', $known) .
')[/ ]+(?<version>[0-9.|a-zA-Z.]*)#';
if (!preg_match_all($pattern, $u_agent, $matches)) {
    // we have no matching number just continue
}

// see how many we have
$i = count($matches['browser']);
if ($i != 1) {
    //we will have two since we are not using 'other' argument yet
    //see if version is before or after the name
    if (strripos($u_agent,"Version") < strripos($u_agent,$ub)){
        $version= $matches['version'][0];
    }
    else {
        $version= $matches['version'][1];
    }
}
else {
    $version= $matches['version'][0];
}

// check if we have a number
if ($version==null || $version=="") {$version="?";}

return array(
    'userAgent' => $u_agent,
    'name'      => $bname,
    'version'   => $version,
    'platform'  => $platform,
    'pattern'    => $pattern
);
} 

// now try it
$ua=getBrowser();

if ($ua['name'] == 'Internet Explorer')
{ header( 'Location: http://www.aliahealthcare.com/Register-IE.php' ) ; }
else {  header( 'Location: http://aliahealthcare.com/New-User.php' ) ;}

?>
```

Comment: strripos() should be available since php 5, so: what php version do you have?

Comment: Which line is line 65 for completeness?

Comment: check the user agent strings by printing them out and then see what is different about them. this page should offer a lot of advice on how to detect browsers using php: http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php

Comment: @DamienPirsy Its been available since PHP 4

Comment: @Mob not according to the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strripos.php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check to see what version of PHP you are running by calling phpinfo() in a document.

```
 strripos - PHP5
 strrpos - PHP4/5
```

If you are running php4 change it to strrpos(....), it is the still the same format.

Depending on your hosting server you can force php5 by adding the following lines to your htaccess

```
 AddType x-mapp-php5 .php
 AddHandler x-mapp-php5 .php
```

Comment: Thanks that works, odd thing is it works in IE Firefox, and Chrome with no issue only found the error when running an android browser or safari?

Comment: IE, Firefox and Chrome may end up having 1 match and thus executing the else rather than the if($i!=1){}. Then they would never encounter the strripos and thus not raise an error. Remove that if and see if it works on Firefox etc.

Answer (score 3):

You are probably using PHP4, which doesn't support [`strripos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strripos.php).

You can check your version with `echo PHP_VERSION`.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the PHP 4 answers, another thing is your regular expression user agent check.

PHP has included the `get_browser()` function which has been available since PHP 4.

All you really need to do is :

```
$browser = get_browser(null, true);

if (strtolower($browser['browser']) == 'firefox'){
   header() //redirect to wherever
}
```

Or just use a switch statement.

> Note :
>
> In order for this to work, your browscap configuration setting in
>   php.ini must point to the correct location of the browscap.ini file on
>   your system.
>
> browscap.ini is not bundled with PHP, but you may find an up-to-date »
>   php_browscap.ini file here.
>
> While browscap.ini contains information on many browsers, it relies on
>   user updates to keep the database current. The format of the file is
>   fairly self-explanatory.

http://browsers.garykeith.com/downloads.asp

Comment: put this code together some time ago, just realized it was giving an issue. But thanks for the advice ! Also the code works in firefox, chrome, and IE

Answer (score 0):

According to the error, PHP is not aware about `strripos()`.

I suppose you are using PHP4, since this function was introduced in PHP5.

Answer (score -1):

This could happen if you are using a version of PHP before 5; `strripos` was added in PHP5.