# PHP script works on one server but not the other

Tags: php, apache

I have a feeling its due to the differences in PHP version installed.  The server that doesn't properly execute the code is running PHP Version 4.3.9.

Here is the section of code that doesn't work.

```
// Function to find browser name
function getBrowser() { 
    $u_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']; 
    $bname = 'Unknown';
    $platform = 'Unknown';
    $version= "";

    //First get the platform?
    if (preg_match('/linux/i', $u_agent)) {
        $platform = 'Linux';
    }
    elseif (preg_match('/macintosh|mac os x/i', $u_agent)) {
        $platform = 'Mac';
    }
    elseif (preg_match('/windows|win32/i', $u_agent)) {
        $platform = 'Windows';
    }

    // Next get the name of the useragent yes seperately and for good reason
    if(preg_match('/MSIE/i',$u_agent) && !preg_match('/Opera/i',$u_agent)) 
    { 
        $bname = 'Internet Explorer'; 
        $ub = "MSIE"; 
    } 
    elseif(preg_match('/Firefox/i',$u_agent)) 
    { 
        $bname = 'Mozilla Firefox'; 
        $ub = "Firefox"; 
    } 
    elseif(preg_match('/Chrome/i',$u_agent)) 
    { 
        $bname = 'Google Chrome'; 
        $ub = "Chrome"; 
    } 
    elseif(preg_match('/Safari/i',$u_agent)) 
    { 
        $bname = 'Apple Safari'; 
        $ub = "Safari"; 
    } 
    elseif(preg_match('/Opera/i',$u_agent)) 
    { 
        $bname = 'Opera'; 
        $ub = "Opera"; 
    } 
    elseif(preg_match('/Netscape/i',$u_agent)) 
    { 
        $bname = 'Netscape'; 
        $ub = "Netscape"; 
    } 
    elseif(preg_match('/Android/i',$u_agent)) 
    { 
        $bname = 'Android'; 
        $ub = "Android"; 
    }
    elseif(preg_match('/iPad/i',$u_agent)) 
    { 
        $bname = 'iPad'; 
        $ub = "iPad"; 
    } 
    elseif(preg_match('/iPhone/i',$u_agent)) 
    { 
        $bname = 'iPhone'; 
        $ub = "iPhone"; 
    } 
    elseif(preg_match('/BlackBerry/i',$u_agent)) 
    { 
        $bname = 'BlackBerry'; 
        $ub = "BlackBerry"; 
    } 
    // finally get the correct version number
    $known = array('Version', $ub, 'other');
    $pattern = '#(?<browser>' . join('|', $known) .
    ')[/ ]+(?<version>[0-9.|a-zA-Z.]*)#';
    if (!preg_match_all($pattern, $u_agent, $matches)) {
        // we have no matching number just continue
    }

    // see how many we have
    $i = count($matches['browser']);
    if ($i != 1) {
        //we will have two since we are not using 'other' argument yet
        //see if version is before or after the name
        if (strripos($u_agent,"Version") < strripos($u_agent,$ub)){
            $version= $matches['version'][0];
        }
        else {
            $version= $matches['version'][1];
        }
    }
    else {
        $version= $matches['version'][0];
    }

    // check if we have a number
    if ($version==null || $version=="") {$version="?";}

    return array(
        'userAgent' => $u_agent,
        'name'      => $bname,
        'version'   => $version,
        'platform'  => $platform,
        'pattern'    => $pattern
    );
} 

// now try it
$ua=getBrowser();
// Make browser and variables readable
$browser = $ua['name'] . " v" . $ua['version'];
$user_agent = $ua['userAgent'];
```

*edit:* Clarification, here are the outputted error messages (thanks for the heads up)

Warning: Compilation failed: unrecognized character after (?< at offset 3 in /var/www/vhosts/staging.xxxxxxxxx.com/httpdocs/feedback/feedback-accept.php on line 150

Notice: Undefined index: browser in /var/www/vhosts/staging.xxxxxxxxx.com/httpdocs/feedback/feedback-accept.php on line 155

Fatal error: Call to undefined function: strripos() in /var/www/vhosts/staging.xxxxxxxxx.com/httpdocs/feedback/feedback-accept.php on line 159

Thanks for the help you guys the information and advice has been excellent.

[Here is the phpinfo() of the server the script doesn't work on](http://pastebin.com/QLA84AW5)

Comment: "It doesn't work" is *never* a good error description. Please describe what goes wrong, what error messages you get, etc.

Comment: @Eric Can you Post the error you are getting?

Comment: While not having to do with your issue directly, you are running *ancient* releases of both PHP and Apache, which include security holes.  You really need to update to newer versions of each.  (Your kernel is pretty old too.)

Comment: *Please* don't try and sniff the user's browser for anything important, it can only ever end in tears. And if you decide you need to write a function to do something, it's a good idea to Google the function name you have chosen. If you had, you would almost certainly have found [`get_browser()`](http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without seeing the actual error is pretty hard, but I guess that the culprit is [strripos()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strripos.php), which is available only on PHP > 5

**Edit after your update**: I guessed right. And, incidentally, while looking on here, I found this:

[Fatal error: Call to undefined function: strripos()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7790424/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-strripos)

which has a code veeery similar to yours and an accepted solution, you might refer to that SO question then (be sure to credit the answerers there if you find it useful)

Answer (score 1):

There's a PHP function that is valid for your PHP version.

It's called "get_browser" and it basically does the same thing your function does.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php

Answer (score 0):

Check if the delimeter set for the regular expression is `#` and not `/` that is set by default.

that's for the preg_match call

```
$pattern = '#(?<browser>' . join('|', $known) .
')[/ ]+(?<version>[0-9.|a-zA-Z.]*)#';
```